# algorithm to simulate multiplication by addition

Tags: algorithm, multiplication, addition

How to design an algorithm to simulate multiplication by addition. input two integers. they may be zero, positive or negative..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
def multiply(a, b):                                                                                                                                                               
    if (a == 1):
        return b
    elif (a == 0):
        return 0
    elif (a < 0):
        return -multiply(-a, b)
    else:
        return b + multiply(a - 1, b)
```

Comment: question is about simulating multiplication without using multiply function... you may only use addition..

Comment: This is a recursive function. If you step through the code, you'll see that it _is_ only doing addition (and calling itself repeatedly).

Comment: i think he meant the multiplication of your '-' signs

Comment: Technically you don't need to check the case where a==1.

Comment: @mikola since he is using a recursive algorithm i think he is using the a==1 case as a base case....without which his code would return 0 no matter what :)

Comment: @enjay: Since no actual multiplication is used, the early bail out for a == 1 is not needed. In case a == 1 the else would be called and b + multiply( 0, b ) -> b + 0 would be returned and all is fine. Ergo the case a==1 is not needed.

Comment: @Saurabh: The multiplication at the "-" signs can easily be dropped by writing 0-... instead.

Comment: I got it.. very clever and elegant solution... is this python syntax?

Comment: @Dr.Acula how do you think recursively? This seems to me to be a very difficult skill :-)

Comment: @Saurabh Here are my guidelines for thinking recursively:
1.  Consider *all* your base cases.
2.  Recursive calls must be made on a smaller element or subset.
3.  Believe in the correctness of the recursive call. If you know you've considered *all* of your base cases, and you have considered exactly what you are trying to do for the recursive step, then recursion will do the rest. Recursion is a tricky thing to wrap your head around initially. Once you understand it and use it more, though, it makes conceptualizing your problem a lot easier, because you can consider each part individually.

Answer (score 1):

some pseudocode:

```
function multiply(x, y)
  if abs(x) = x and abs(y) = y or abs(x) <> x and abs(y) <> y then sign = 'plus'
  if abs(x) = x and abs(y) <> y or abs(x) <> x and abs(y) = y then sign = 'minus'

 res = 0
 for i = 0 to abs(y)
  res = res + abs(x)
 end

 if sign = 'plus' return res
    else return -1 * res

end function
```

Comment: This is a very simple solution.. matching my solution.. pretty straightforward

Comment: according to the KISS principle (Keep It Stupid Simple) :))

Answer (score 1):

```
val:= 0
bothNegative:=false

if(input1 < 0) && if(input2 < 0)
  bothNegative=true
if(bothNegative)
  smaller_number:=absolute_value_of(smaller_number)
for [i:=absolute_value_of(bigger_number);i!=0;i--]
do val+=smaller_number

return val;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    mul(a,b)
    {
    sign1=sign2=1;
    if(a==0 || b==0)
return 0;
if(a<0){
    sign1=-1;
    a=-a;
    }
    if(b<0){
    sign2=-1;
    b=-b;
    }
    s=a;
    for(i=1;i<b;i++)
    s+=a;
    if(sign1==sign2)
    return s;
    else
    return -s;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this for integers:

```
int multiply(int a, int b)
{
    int product = 0;
    int i;
    if ( b > 0 )
    {
        for(i = 0; i < b ; i++)
        {
            product += a;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for(i = 0; i > b ; i--)
        {
            product -= a;
        }
    }

    return product;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got here because I was looking for multiplication algorithm without using `*` operation. All I see here is just adding or subtracting number n-times. It's **O(n)** and it's ok, but...

#### If you have `bitwise shift` operations you can get **O(log n)** algorithm for multiplication.

Here is my pseudocode:

```
function mul(n, x)
    if n < 0 then   # 'n' cannot be negative
        n := -n
        x := -x
    endif

    y := 0
    while n != 0 do
        if n % 2 == 0 then
            x := x << 1     # x := x + x
            n := n >> 1     # n := n / 2
        else
            y := y + x
            x := x << 1     # x := x + x
            n := n - 1      # n := (n-1)/2
            n := n >> 1
        endif
    endwhile

    return y                # y = n * x
end
```

Remember that function above for **`mul(1000000, 2)` is O(log 1000000)** and for **`mul(2, 1000000)` is only O(log 2)**.

Of course, you will get the same results, but keep in mind that the order of the parameters in function call does matter.

### Edit: sidenote for using `n % 2`

#### Implementation of `n % 2` using `bitwise shift`

It's pretty straightforward. First divide `n` by 2, then multiply `n` by 2 and check if `n` has changed. Pseudocode:

```
function is_even(n)
    n_original := n
    n := n >> 1        # n := n / 2
    n := n << 1        # n := n * 2
    if n = n_original then
        return true    # n is even
    else
        return false   # n is not even
    endif
end
```

#### Implementation of `n % 2` using `bitwise and`

```
function is_even(n)
    if n and 1 = 0 then
        return true
    else
        return false
    endif
end
```