# Recursive definition of integer multiplication

Tags: java, function, recursion

This is the function that multiplies `a` and `b`:

```
0    int mult(int a, int b){
1      if(a==0){
2        return 0;
3      } else{
4        a=a-1;
5        int c = mult(a,b);
6        int d = b + c;
7        return d;
8      }
9    }
```

I am playing with arguments `2` and `3`: the result is `6`, but why?

In line 5 I will get `0` after the second `a=a-1;` and then `d` is `3` then `return 3` and not `6`. Am I stupid or is it also confusing for you?

Comment: perhaps you are referring to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6577828/algorithm-to-simulate-multiplication-by-addition

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Let's go step by step [ mult(2, 3) ]: -**

```
 1. (a = 2, b = 3) : - 
     a = 1;
     c = mult(1, 3); ---->    2. (a = 1, b = 3) : - 
                                  a = 0;
                                  c = mult(0, 3); -----> 3. (a = 0, b == 3) : -
                                                             return 0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                  c = 0;
                                  d = (b + c) = 3;
                                  return 3; 
------------------------------------------------------------------
     c = 3;
     d = b + c == 3 + 3 = 6

     return 6;
```

**NOTE**: -

States of recursive calls are stored on stack. So, as the base condition is reached, the stack starts unwinding, passing the result of the current call to the previous call, thus reaching the state where it started with a final result.

Comment: how ``c`` is becoming ``3`` in the last row. i dont understand this

Comment: mult(1, 3) returns 3 -> see last row 2nd column.

Comment: thanks Rohit, now i got it, so the recursion goes inside and ends with last result outwards.. it is a little confusing... you saved me!

Comment: @doniyor. You're welcome :) Remember, states of recursive calls are stored on stack. So, as the base condition is reached, the stack starts unwinding, thus reaching the state where it started with a result.

Comment: @AmitD. What? didn't get you!!

Comment: @AmitD. Ok. Just a matter of few `hiephens` and `pipes`, and `plus` signs. Its easy.

Comment: @Rohit yeah, thats right. the callee goes deeper until it reaches the base state and every ``return``-value on the way will be saved on stack. right?

Answer (score 6):

You're getting confused by the recursion.

```
mult(2, 3):
  calls mult(1, 3)
    mult(1, 3):
      calls mult(0, 3)
        mult(0, 3):
          returns 0
      d = 3 + 0
      returns 3
  d = 3 + 3
  returns 6
```

Comment: now i got it Jon, sorry for not giving the check for your right answer, Rohits answer made me finally understand the flow of steps..

Comment: hey Jon, wow, you posted to my question!! :) Great Honor!. thank you!