# How to design an algorithm that multiplies two floats without '*'?

Tags: c++, algorithm, ieee-754

How do I design an algorithm that takes two floats and multiplies them using only addition, bit shifting and bitwise operations?

I have already found [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6577828/algorithm-to-simulate-multiplication-by-addition) like this for integers, but that doesn't work with floats.
I have also found [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6577828/algorithm-to-simulate-multiplication-by-addition) that is much like what I need but log is also prohibited in my case.

The floats are stored according to the IEEE754 standard. I have also tried to keep their exponent part, and bitwise multiply their fractional part with no luck.

Comment: Show what you've tried.

Comment: Separate the components of the float, perform the appropriate operations, paste it back together again. It's FAR from trivial tho'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point, an IEEE754 number `x = (-1)^s * c * b^q` is represented by `s,c,b,q` , all are integers. for Two floating point numbers with the same base `b` is the same.

So the multiplication of two floating point numbers `x` and `y` is:

`(-1)^(s1+s2)*c1*c2*b^(q1+q2)` so the new floating point is represented by: `s1+s2, c1*c2, b q1+q2` so you only have left to deal with multiplication of `c1` and `c2`, both are integers so you are done.